# How to print pdf file using Python, in silent mode and without install other applications

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a pdf file using Python, in silent mode and without install other applications.

In the follow example, python will print the file, but not in silent mode (opening Adobe without closing it at the end of printing process)

```
import win32api

file_to_print = '/path/....'
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", stampa, None, ".", 0)
```

A solution could be to add the following lines to the code for closing Adobe after 4 sec, but if the file is to large, Adobe would not have enough time to print all the pages..

```
time.sleep(4)
os.system("TASKKILL/F/IMAcroRD32.exe")
```

I prefer not to install other apps to solve the problem...

It is possible that there is no other ways to print a pdf in silent mode?